# How can I get my random orange box up and under the other orange box above it?

Tags: css

Hi is this even possible? i've tried everything I need to get that orange box up and under the other orange box? here is my code, I'm going mad!!

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="nav1"></div>
    <div id="nav2"></div>

    <div id="box3"></div>
    <div id="box4"></div>
    <div id="box5"></div>
    <div id="box5"></div>
    <div id="box3"></div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#box3
{ 
  width:250px;
  height:200px; 
  background-color:#F30; float:left; 
} 
#box4
{ 
  width:500px;
  height:400px; 
  background-color:#F00; 
  float:left; 
} 
#box5
{ 
  width:250px;
  height:200px; 
  background-color:#C00; 
  float:left; 
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W5uE3/)

Comment: [link](http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=en&sa=N&authuser=0&biw=1108&bih=619&tbm=isch&tbnid=3mq8GGdWUWNVRM:&imgrefurl=http://www.gizmowatch.com/xbox-360-dashboard-features.html&docid=5OuuqS6yDLtpSM&imgurl=http://www.instablogsimages.com/1/2011/12/07/new_xbox_360_dashboard_be7bf.jpg&w=600&h=337&ei=qQV0UNntFIbetAa1sIHoDA&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=398&sig=117532703373234184946&page=3&tbnh=99&tbnw=176&start=35&ndsp=20&ved=1t:429,r:16,s:35,i:310&tx=104&ty=60)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to achieve if that helps any

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W5uE3/

html:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="nav1"></div>
    <div id="nav2"></div>

    <div id = 'cont1'>    
        <div class="box3"></div>
        <div class="box3"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="box4"></div>
    <div class="box5"></div>
    <div class="box5"></div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

css:

```
#container { 
    width: 1000px; 
}
.box3{ 
    width:250px; 
    height:200px; 
    background-color:#F30; 
    float:left; 
} 
#box4{ 
    width:500px; 
    height:400px; 
    background-color:#F00; 
    float:left; 
} 
.box5{ 
    width:250px; 
    height:200px; 
    background-color:#C00; 
    float:left; 
}
#cont1 {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
}
```

You don't need to use z-index, just an extra container. And to change the multiple ids to classes.

Comment: Could you tell me the difference between Id's and classes?

Comment: @user1731516 Check out this link: http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: @user1731516 You can accept an answer by clicking the tick to the left of the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

First you can't use any div with same id, you have 2 div's with `box5` id and 2 div's with id `box3`, please consider changing these to use a `class` instead of an `id`.
then

You should use the `clear:both` on the div you want placed in bottom other.

For example:

```
<div id="box4" style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="box3" style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: i delete your div with same id

Comment: It is worth telling the OP about using classes, rather than just saying to delete them.